# How to enlarge unused space of tcolorbox interior to the bottom of a page?

Tags: tcolorbox

How to enlarge unused space of tcolorbox interior to the bottom of a page?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most, many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\NewTColorBox{solution}{+O{}}{%
  breakable, enhanced,sharpish corners, colframe=blue!50,colback=white,coltitle=blue!50!black,
  fonttitle=\itshape\bfseries, parbox = false,
  boxrule=0.5mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  code={\if@twoside\tcbset{check odd page, toggle enlargement, toggle left and right}\fi},
  left=1mm,
  right=\dimexpr(\marginparsep+\marginparwidth)\relax,
  grow to right by=\dimexpr(\marginparsep+\marginparwidth)\relax,
  title={},
  label={},
  attach title to upper=\quad,
  after upper={\par\hfill%
      {}},
  lowerbox=ignored,
  #1
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key `height fixed for=last`

Comment: Is a solution for unroken tcolorbox?